# Implementing logout( timer event) from the server in iOS

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am trying to implement automatic logout of the user from the server in iPad. This is the code my senior has been using.

```
- (void) Logout:(id) sender
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {   
        NSDate *date    = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:logoutUser];
        if (timerLogout) {
            [timerLogout invalidate];
            timerLogout = nil;
        }
        timerLogout = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:date interval:logoutUser target:self selector:@selector(CallToLogout:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runLoop addTimer:timerLogout forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [runLoop run];
    }
}
```

The problem i face is that for example, when the time is to automatic logout is 60 mins, the iPad logouts from the server at around 20 mins.. Not sure why this happens?

If more information is needed, I can provide.. Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Kinda weird that he's not simply using the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` class method on `NSTimer` (which automatically adds it to a run loop for you), but I suppose this does the same thing, eh? :D

Comment: - Add an `NSLog` and check that the `date` is correct in the `Logout:` method. - Add an `NSLog` and see how often/when `CallToLogout` is being called. - Further, can any other part of your code call `CallToLogout` (assuming this is the only logout method)?

Comment: How do you know the iPad logs out from the server after 20 minutes? Is said `CallToLogout:` method called in your app after 20 minutes? Or, are you perhaps losing a session (in which case, it could a persistence issue on the server side)?

Comment: I have only one part in my code that logs out the user, that is CallToLogout-> that produces an alert saying you are logged out...

Comment: only one function call to CallToLogout...

Comment: my point is timerCorpLogout = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:date interval:logout target:self selector:@selector(CallToLogout:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; looks wrong.. am i right to say this?

Comment: should the initWithFireDate be referring to the current date? instead of the date that it needs to be called in...

Comment: If your method is being called early, it sounds like the `date` may be wrong, which is set by the `logoutUser` variable. So, it sounds like `logoutUser` may be wrong. Put an `NSLog` (or breakpoint) and see.

Comment: No, `initWithFireDate` refers to a date that it's meant to fire in the future, so this is correct.

Comment: In such `logoutUser` should equal 60 * 60 = 3600 (seconds), or one hour in the future.

Comment: then the interval part is also correct?

Comment: ya.. it is done that way...

Comment: the iPad logs out from the server after 20 minutes when i leave the app idle...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23481/discussion-between-lakesh-and-jrg-developer)